# issue with jquery slider and amchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, accordion, amcharts

Hi im using line chart from [amchart](http://www.amcharts.com/) and it is not loading inside a slider but if i put it outside it works fine 
the slider is made using Jquery, so any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this link http://blog.amcharts.com/2012/08/displaying-javascript-charts-in-tabs-or.html?m=1

Me too have the same problem but it was conflict with jquery tab... and also i was using amchart version 2.7 when i upgrade it to `2.7.7`. Its working fine for me...I know its a late reply but it may help someone who is struggling with it...

Comment: thanks for the answer my website is running now and I even forget how i did fix it